# How to attach alt and title attributes to images uploaded by Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This task is simple if each row in the database tables stores one image only. But when storing multiple images using Carrierwave in a JSON / text field, how to save additional data such as `alt` or `title` attributes?

Comment: Can you add colums to the database for alt and title?   If you can't do that, you'll have to store them in a separate table and join them.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, Carrierwave stores multiple images for an entity (e.g. an article) in one row. Multiple images are stored as JSON object or serializable text in one field of that row. I can add title and alt fields but then each image would occupy one row. I wonder, if Carrierwave supports storing those attributes in nested JSON structure holding file names along with extra data.